# .htaccess includes old part of url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a redirect of sorts for an old url structure to a new url structure.

Old url structure:

```
index.php?page=protocols&id=1
```

New url structure:

```
/protocols/view/1
```

This is my .htaccess, but it is not redirecting correctly.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=protocols&id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ \/protocols\/view\/%1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It is redirecting to `/protocols/view/1?page=protocols&id=1`

How do I have it redirect correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `QSD` "query string discard" flag in your rule to remove the additional string from your new URL

Change

```
RewriteRule ^ \/protocols\/view\/%1 [R,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^ \/protocols\/view\/%1 [R,QSD,L]
```

If your server version doesn't support `QSD` then simply put an empty question mark at the end of the rule's  destination url

```
RewriteRule ^ \/protocols\/view\/%1?  [R,L]
```

Comment: No need to escape the slashes in the _substitution_ either.